# ios - When validating the bundle, error says that bundle is invalid, but I made sure it is matching

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

When I validate an archive, I get the error:

```
This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [.99] in the Info.plist file must be period-separated list of non-negative integers.
```

I am not entirely sure why that error happened. I have version .99 everywhere. Would anyone know why this happens?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: @Adam good point...trying it now :)

Comment: :) that did it! I can accept your answer if you want to post it as the answer.

Comment: Software versioning goes `Major.Minor.patch`, instead, you went `.Minor.Patch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "The value for key CFBundleVersion [.99] in the Info.plist file must be period-separated list of non-negative integers", you should make your version number `0.99`.